# Firebase Authentication restrict to version

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an app with Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Authentication. Now we're changing our datamodel e.g. migrate the database manually to the new model, so we want the users to update / don't want them to login with an older version because they would "destroy" the data and bring them back into the old model. Now, is there any possibility from Firebase to allow only certain app versions to login? Or should we have had implemented this manually with a Firebase RemoteConfig entry or something like this? Is there any possibility to do this retrospectively?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this manually: Create a users collection, and record what version are they using. Next, in your app, on login, check the version before anything else, if old, force them to go through the update process, if new, do nothing. When all users are converted, release a new version whthout this code... or keep it for a future update. Cheers